# Can I backup my phone or install TWRP recovery while stuck in Lineage OS recovery?

Tags: backup, twrp, data-recovery, boot-loop, lineageos

Highly unfortunately for me, I had thought it was a great idea not to make any backups when going to test if I was properly able to upgrade/downgrade Lineage OS versions. I had replaced my TWRP recovery with Lineage OS's recovery, and then I "upgraded" to the same Lineage OS version I had currently been running, and my phone ran into a boot loop (The never-ending Lineage OS bootup screen). I believe I ran into this boot loop because I might have previously accidentally installed TWRP's "system" app, and this would have been a problem due to LineageOS's enforcement of priv-app whitelisting rules.

My device is a: LG H830

What I do have: Root, an unlocked bootloader, ADB/Fastboot, the TWRP recovery file

I believe I am screwed and that there's no way out of this except just factory resetting/formatting everything. If I was correct in my research, my phone model blocks all fastboot commands, excluding bootloader + "unlock" related commands, and as a result, I don't believe I am able to do a backup using ADB (I tried `adb backup -all` and it didn't work). Lineage OS recovery has no way of backing up files, and I don't believe it is possible to use it to flash TWRP recovery. All I need to be able to do is to save/backup my photos (Which are located in my internal storage). I think it is highly probable that I have finally entered into a hole that I can't get out of. However, if anyone has any ideas about what I could do to either back up what's on my phone (Mainly photos/internal storage if possible) or to flash TWRP without resetting/formatting everything, it would be substantially appreciated. Thank you!

Sources I checked out:

[Team Win Recovery Project for the LG G5](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/recovery-h830-team-win-recovery-project-for-the-lg-g5.3349499/) - Post indicates that LG G5 H830 has flashing locked

[Backup & Restore Android with ADB](https://www.paulligocki.com/backup-restore-android-with-adb/) - Backing up via ADB would have worked if I was able to successfully boot into Lineage OS and approve the backup operation, but I can't because I am limited to being able to boot in everything except system

[Does Lineage Recovery have backup?](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/g1zpw9/does_lineage_recovery_have_backup/) - This is a post with answer(s) that designate the fact that Lineage OS's recovery isn't able to backup

Comment: How did you first manage to install Los in your device if not through fastboot? Normally, my suggestion would have been to issue the command 'fastboot boot twrp.img' to temporarily into TWRP and take the backup from there.